# How to generate a unique range of numbers in PHP

Tags: php

I've been trying to write a code that will generate specific details using PHP. So far, this is what I've been able to come up with:

```
$meta_key = array();
$meta_key[1] = 'nickname';
$meta_key[2] = 'first_name';
$meta_key[3] = 'last_name';
$meta_key[4] = 'description';
$meta_key[5] = 'rich_editing';
$meta_key[6] = 'comment_shortcuts';
$meta_key[7] = 'admin_color';
$meta_key[8] = 'use_ssl';
$meta_key[9] = 'show_admin_bar_front';
$meta_key[10] = 'capabilities';
$meta_key[11] = 'user_level';
$meta_key[12] = 'dismissed_pointers';
$meta_key[13] = 'key_confirm';
$meta_key[14] = 'session_tokens';

$meta_value = array();
$meta_value[1] = '';
$meta_value[2] = '';
$meta_value[3] = '';
$meta_value[4] = '';
$meta_value[5] = 'true';
$meta_value[6] = 'false';
$meta_value[7] = 'fresh';
$meta_value[8] = '0';
$meta_value[9] = 'true';
$meta_value[10] = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}';
$meta_value[11] = '0';
$meta_value[12] = '';
$meta_value[13] = '';
$meta_value[14] = '';

for ($id=1; $id<=14; $id++) {
echo "('" . $id . "', " . "'" . $meta_key[$id] . "', '" . $meta_value[$id] . "'),<br />";
}
```

And this is the result:

```
('1', 'nickname', ''),
('2', 'first_name', ''),
('3', 'last_name', ''),
('4', 'description', ''),
('5', 'rich_editing', 'true'),
('6', 'comment_shortcuts', 'false'),
('7', 'admin_color', 'fresh'),
('8', 'use_ssl', '0'),
('9', 'show_admin_bar_front', 'true'),
('10', 'capabilities', 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}'),
('11', 'user_level', '0'),
('12', 'dismissed_pointers', ''),
('13', 'key_confirm', ''),
('14', 'session_tokens', ''),
```

But what I really want to achieve is to get it to show in a range of numbers, let's say from 1-5. Something like this:

```
('1', 'nickname', ''),
('1', 'first_name', ''),
('1', 'last_name', ''),
('1', 'description', ''),
('1', 'rich_editing', 'true'),
('1', 'comment_shortcuts', 'false'),
('1', 'admin_color', 'fresh'),
('1', 'use_ssl', '0'),
('1', 'show_admin_bar_front', 'true'),
('1', 'capabilities', 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}'),
('1', 'user_level', '0'),
('1', 'dismissed_pointers', ''),
('1', 'key_confirm', ''),
('1', 'session_tokens', ''),
```

And the next one will be 2, 3, 4, and so on.

Comment: Hey, c'mon. I just asked a question. Why voting down my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not build your array like this in the first place?

```
$data = array(
   array(
       'nickname' => '...',
       'first_name' => 'John', 
        etc...
   ),
   array(
        'nickname' => '...',
        'first_name' => 'Fred',
        etc...
   )
);
```

Then you don't need multiple arrays to track names, just one, and a couple loops:

```
foreach($data as $id => $person) {
   foreach($person as $key => $value) {
        echo "($id) $key -> $value";
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't just want to get the keys and values. I also want to include some numbers, just like this: `('1', 'nickname', 'john'), ('1', 'first_name', 'John')` etc. Such that the number `1`, will appear, and so on.

Comment: @SamuelAsor Marc's code would do that. You just need to modify the `echo` line slightly to conform to the exact output format you want.

Comment: Okay, I get you. But how do I make it print out in series. Let's say `('1', 'nickname', 'john'), ('1', 'first_name', 'John'), ('2', 'nickname', 'john'), ('2', 'first_name', 'John')` and so on.?

Comment: that's exactly what the above foreach loops do... the actual formatting of the output is trivial.